# what is the difference between a method within JS function and to it's prototype?

Tags: javascript

As output of both the below JS class is same, then what is special here with prototype?

One of the feature of prototype is get rid of duplicate code, in what case this is possible with prototype?

**1.**

```
   function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sayName = function () {
            console.log(this.name);
        };
    }
    var person1 = new Person("Nicholas");
    person1.sayName();
```

**2.**

```
 function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Person.prototype.sayName = function () {
        console.log(this.name);
    };
    var person1 = new Person("Nicholas");
    person1.sayName();
```

Comment: Number 1 is a method that belongs to the class. Number 2 is a method that belongs to an instantiated object.

Comment: No, prototype methods don't get rid of duplicate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign a property by using *`prototype`* then those properties will be shared through out all the instances of the *class/constructor* which has the particular *`prototype`*. But assigning a property using `this` inside of the constructor will be instance-specific. They cannot be shared with other instances. Each instances will have their own value in it.

Comment: Nothing is "private" when it's a property?

Comment: @Bergi What I meant was,  those properties are private to the instance. Other instances cannot share it. Every instances have their own value in those properties.

Comment: They don't share it with other instances, yes, but "private" usually means that those "cannot access it". I'd recommend to use the term "instance-specific" instead.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for suggesting the right term to describe it.